# Vertica: How to create a column using case?

Tags: sql, vertica

I have a `stats` table like

```
name | age | sound
------------------
 m   | 5   |   a
 a   | 3   |   c
 c   | 5   |   d
 f   | 1   |   j
 d   | 6   |   r
 c   | 55  |   d
```

and I add a column called `appearance`

```
ALTER TABLE stats
    ADD appearance INTEGER DEFAULT case
                         when age > 4 then 'red'
                         when name = f then 'blue'

        end
```

and get a table like:

```
name | age | sound | appearance
--------------------------------
 m   | 5   |   a   |   red
 a   | 3   |   c   |   <null>
 c   | 5   |   d   |   red
 f   | 1   |   j   |   blue
 d   | 6   |   r   |   red
 c   | 55  |   d   |   red
```

Then, I want to add another column, called `flavor`

```
ALTER TABLE stats
    ADD flavor varchar(20) case
                    WHEN appearance = 'red' THEN 'apple'
                    WHEN appearance = 'blue' THEN 'blueberry'
    END
```

But I keep receiving the error:

```
[Vertica][VJDBC](7344) ROLLBACK: default expressions may not refer to other columns with default expressions
```

How do I create a second column from the first column that I created?

Comment: You may be better off using a view for the "derived" columns.  The values are only set when the data is loaded into the table, so the derived value is not guaranteed to be up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the error message:
Looks like string can not refer to

[Vertica]VJDBC
ERROR 7344: string expressions may not refer to other columns with string expressions

Just a guess. Sorry, I have no vertica database to test

```
ALTER TABLE stats
    ADD appearance INTEGER DEFAULT case
                         when age > 4 then 'red'
                         when name = f then 'blue'
           else ''
        end
```

May be try this

```
ALTER TABLE stats
    ADD flavor varchar(20) case
                    WHEN appearance = 'red' THEN 'apple'
                    WHEN appearance = 'blue' THEN 'blueberry'
       else ''
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to drop the DEFAULT of a column you want to use as the input of another DEFAULT.

And, as @user3380585 pointed out, you might want to check for the right types, as `'red'` can't be an INTEGER.

Try this script:

```
CREATE TABLE stats(name,age,sound) AS (                                                                                                                                                                                                       
          SELECT 'm',5,'a'
UNION ALL SELECT 'a',3,'c'
UNION ALL SELECT 'c',5,'d'
UNION ALL SELECT 'f',1,'j'
UNION ALL SELECT 'd',6,'r'
UNION ALL SELECT 'c',55,'d'
)
;
SELECT * FROM stats;
-- out  name | age | sound 
-- out ------+-----+-------
-- out  a    |   3 | c
-- out  c    |   5 | d
-- out  c    |  55 | d
-- out  d    |   6 | r
-- out  f    |   1 | j
-- out  m    |   5 | a
ALTER TABLE stats ADD appearance CHAR(4) DEFAULT 
    CASE    
        WHEN age > 4    THEN 'red'    
        WHEN name = 'f' THEN 'blue'    
    END;

ALTER TABLE stats ALTER COLUMN appearance DROP DEFAULT;

ALTER TABLE stats ADD flavor varchar(20) DEFAULT
    CASE
      WHEN appearance = 'red' THEN 'apple'
      WHEN appearance = 'blue' THEN 'blueberry'
    END;

SELECT * FROM stats;
-- out  name | age | sound | appearance |  flavor   
-- out ------+-----+-------+------------+-----------
-- out  a    |   3 | c     |            | 
-- out  c    |   5 | d     | red        | apple
-- out  c    |  55 | d     | red        | apple
-- out  d    |   6 | r     | red        | apple
-- out  f    |   1 | j     | blue       | blueberry
-- out  m    |   5 | a     | red        | apple
-- out (6 rows)
-- out 
-- out Time: First fetch (6 rows): 3.510 ms. All rows formatted: 3.552 ms
```